# не работает метод класса DateTime C#

Tags: c#, datetime

не добавляется час к endTime. Что не так?

```
DateTime startTime = new DateTime();
startTime = DateTime.Now;
for (int i = 0; i < gp.Steps-1; i++)
{
    DateTime endTime = new DateTime();
    endTime = startTime;
    endTime.AddHours(1);
```

Comment: Если вам был дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Тип `DateTime` является иммутабельным. Это значит, что однажды созданный экземпляр никогда не меняется. Поэтому все методы возвращают новый экземпляр:

```
DateTime endTime = startTime.AddHours(1);
```

Comment: "неизменяемый" - наверное больше понятно будет :-)

Answer (score 6):

Вместо данных предложений

```
DateTime endTime = new DateTime();
endTime = startTime;
endTime.AddHours(1);
```

запишите одно предложение

```
DateTime endTime = startTime.AddHours(1);
```

Функция `AddHours` возвращает новый объект `DateTime`, добавляющий заданное число часов к значению данного экземпляра

Имейте в виду, что нет необходимости вызывать конструктор по умолчанию, как вы это делаете

```
DateTime startTime = new DateTime();
startTime = DateTime.Now;
```

Можно сразу же написать

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
```